# Парсинг даты в SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, дата

есть код

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);//здесь включен жесткий режим парсинга, хочу чтобы дата строго соответствовала шаблону
```

но при парсинге строки

```
dateFormat.parse("2020-12-12 10:10:19 +2300")
```

я получаю ошибку из-за зоны, хотя по стандарту RFC822 зона может указываться вплоть до 2359(23 часа 59 минут)
почему так происходит, как правильно распарсить эту зону?

ошибка

```
`Unparseable date: "2020-12-12 10:10:19 +2300"                                               
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)                                                                                       
        at Main.main(Main.java:16)        
            `
```

Comment: Как выглядит ошибка, позвольте взглянуть

Comment: @AVRamones добавил

Comment: Короче от нечего делать поковырялся. Работает корректно только при часовых поясах от -1300 до +1400. Покури документацию)

Comment: да судя по доке все должно работать,да и цифры -1300 +1400 очень странные

Comment: Ну типа часовые пояса идут от -12.00 до + 13.00 официально. так что выглядит похоже

Comment: Если распарсить при помощи `ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-12-12 10:10:19 +2300", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"))`, то будет более осмысленное сообщение: `Text '2020-12-12 10:10:19 +2300' could not be parsed: Zone offset not in valid range: -18:00 to +18:00`, т.е. берет только от -1800 до +1800 включительно.

Comment: примечательно то что,если убрать setLenient то все работает с правильным смещением,но в любом случае,этот метод задает только привязку к шаблону,который вроде как правильный
upd мне кажется дело в шаблоне скорее всего